# how to store the avasset current item URL before changing it to another URL

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avasset, video-editing, avurlasset

I have developed a video Editing app which does basic cropping, trimming etc to video and after changes save the video, what problem m facing is what to do if I want to revert those changes, currently in player view, I change the current item but how can i go to the last item if I want to revert the changes of any of edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by making two player layers and passing URL data between them.